# Python unittest: mock open specific paths (don't mock others)

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

The use-case is that I want to mock the opening of two files `~/.myconf` and `./.myconf` but not the other ones.

I'm testing the setup of a complex object which reads multiple files in its `__init__` and so I'd like to mock some data for some of them, not mock at all for some others.

As an example here is how I mock the conditional opening of those two files, but it feels complex and I find it odd that there's no easy way already built-in that I'm missing.

```py
import builtins
import configparser
import unittest

from textwrap import dedent
from pathlib import Path
from unittest.mock import mock_open

OPEN = builtins.open


def get_hierarchical_config():
    cwd = Path.cwd()
    global_config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    local_config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    global_config.read(Path("~/.myconf").expanduser().resolve())
    local_config.read((cwd / ".myconf").expanduser().resolve())

    full_config.read_dict(global_config)
    full_config.read_dict(local_config)

    return full_config["mysection"]

def get_custom_mock_open(global_conf_str, local_conf_str) -> callable:
    def mocked_open():
        def conditional_open_func(path, *args, **kwargs):
            p = Path(path).expanduser().resolve()
            if p.name == ".myconfig":
                if p.parent == Path.home():
                    return mock_open(read_data=global_conf_str)()
                return mock_open(read_data=local_conf_str)()
            return OPEN(path, *args, **kwargs)

        return conditional_open_func

    return mocked_open

[...]

class TestConfig(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_read_confs(self):

        global_conf = dedent(
            """\
            [mysection]
            no_overwrite=path/to/somewhere
            local_overwrite=ERROR:not overwritten
            syntax_test_key= no/space= problem2
            """
        )
        local_conf = dedent(
            """\
            [mysection]
            local_overwrite=SUCCESS:overwritten
            local_new_key=cool value
            """
        )

        with patch(
            "builtins.open",
            new_callable=get_custom_mock_open(global_conf, local_conf),
        ):
            conf = dict(get_hierarchical_config()) # reads the config files
            target = {
                "no_overwrite": "path/to/somewhere",
                "local_overwrite": "SUCCESS:overwritten",
                "syntax_test_key": "no/space= problem2",
                "local_new_key": "cool value",
            }
            self.assertDictEqual(conf, target)
```

Comment: Did you check [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open)?

Comment: as you can see in the code I shared, I did but it's not conditional on the filename is it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that for some reason. No, I don't think there is something ready to use better than that. If you want to fake the filesystem a lot, you could use [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs) (disclaimer: I'm a contributor), but that would probably be overkill in your case.